# How can I write a single command line that launches a new docker container with interactive bash and executes a few commands in it?

Tags: command-line, docker, command

For example, let's say I want to

```
docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu:18.04 bash
apt update; apt install -y git nano wget; mkdir t; cd t
```

but instead have one a single-line command.

---

I unsuccessfully tried:

```
docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu:18.04 (bash; apt update; apt install -y git nano wget; mkdir t; cd t)
```

and

```
docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu:18.04 "bash; apt update; apt install -y git nano wget; mkdir t; cd t"
```

Comment: I can't see what is interactive about why you are trying to do. Update question to tell us what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: `docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu:18.04 bash` launches an interactive bash in the container.

Comment: It's not clear: are you trying to run the `apt...` commands inside the container?

Comment: Yes. I see that (by looking). However it is not clear about what is interactive about what you are trying to achieve. This may be because it is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor When launching a new docker container by default it doesn't launch any bash. The interactive  bash comes from `--interactive --tty bash`. @roa Indeed, apt... commands inside the container.

Comment: Stop trying to teach me about what docker does, and start telling us **what you are trying to achieve**.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor making it easy for someone to try a program that runs within a docker container. The program has some requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make that a `bash` command, that ends with a final call to `bash` so that you get an interactive subshell:

```
docker run --interactive --tty ubuntu:18.04 bash -c "apt update; apt install -y git nano wget; mkdir t; cd t; exec bash"
```

`exec` exec is necessary to make the new bash the container's main process, which is recommended (it will get interruptions sent to the container).

This said, you should put the `apt` calls in a Dockerfile and generate a derived image that you can start directly with your interactive bash:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt update && apt install -y git nano wget
RUN mkdir /somedir
WORKDIR /somedir
```

Do once for all (or until you want newer versions):

```
docker build -t testbuild .   # done once for all
```

and

```
docker run -it testbuild  # bash already in /somedir
```

Comment: works great, thanks!